# Count the number of values in a String with .split(";")

Tags: java

how can I sucessfully count the numbers of values in a String that are seperated through a semicolon(including empty values)?

I have for example this String:

```
;;C;D;E;F;G
```

The correct number of  values would be '7', but  when I use `.split` it returns the wrong number, because of the empty values.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `System.out.println(";;C;D;E;F;G".split(";").length);` prints `7` to me.

Comment: It prints `7` to me also. There's certainly a mistake with the way you're counting elements.

Comment: Ditto with the two above. I also get a length of 7. What is your method for counting the elements?

Comment: Thanks Pshemo, your solution works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example from your question works fine since

```
System.out.println(";;C;D;E;F;G".split(";").length);
```

prints `7`.

But problem could appear when empty elements are at end of your string like

```
System.out.println(";;C;D;E;F;G;;".split(";").length);
```

which *also* would return `7`. Why is that? Because `split(regex)` uses `split(regex,limit)` version with `limit` set to `0`. This limit represents behaviour of split in which trailing empty elements will be removed.

If you don't want to remove trailing empty elements use negative limit like

```
System.out.println(";;C;D;E;F;G;;".split(";", -1).length);
//                                            ^^-negative limit
```

which will now print `9`.

Comment: Your mind reading power are strong ;)

Answer (score 2):

`String#split()` may return return a wrong number because of the empty values only if the separators are at the tail of text, e.g. `";;C;D;E;F;G;;"`. To avoid that use `text.split(regex, -1)`